# Error: incorrect number of arguments to constructor

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat

Someone could help me.
Despite the similar questions i read, i don't see what is wrong.
Thanks in advance,
Claude

Here is detailed information about error

```
    imac-de-claude:TransactionContract claudevannier$ npx hardhat run ./scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
Error: incorrect number of arguments to constructor
    at ContractFactory.getDeployTransaction (/Users/claudevannier/TransactionContract/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/factory.ts:87:19)
    at ContractFactory.deploy (/Users/claudevannier/TransactionContract/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/factory.ts:105:31)
    at main (/Users/claudevannier/TransactionContract/scripts/deploy.js:11:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
imac-de-claude:TransactionContract claudevannier$
```

Here is my solidity contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract TransactionContract {
    address public accountX;
    address public accountY;
    address public owner;

    event TransactionEvent(address indexed sender, address indexed receiver, uint amount, string eventTrigger);

    constructor(address _accountX, address _accountY) {
        accountX = _accountX;
        accountY = _accountY;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function triggerTransaction(uint _amount, string memory _eventTrigger) public {
        require(msg.sender == accountX, "Only account X can trigger this transaction");
        require(_amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than zero");
        
        // Transfer funds from accountX to accountY
        (bool success, ) = accountY.call{value: _amount}("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed");

        emit TransactionEvent(accountX, accountY, _amount, _eventTrigger);
    }

    // Fallback function to receive ETH
    receive() external payable {}
}
```

here is my script for deploy the contract

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const transac = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("TransactionContract");
  const contract = await transac.deploy();

  await contract.deployed();

  console.log("contract deployed to:", contract.address);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor has this signature: `constructor(address _accountX, address _accountY)`. So it expects two parameters: `_accountX` and `_accountsY`.

When you are deploying, you don't provide any parameters. You should add the parameters to `transac.deploy()` as shown in the ethers documentation (https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/contract/#ContractFactory-deploy) . Or, alternatively, remove the parameters from your constructor - depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Lauri for your answer.

In fact, my project takes in charge another program in PYTHON language that is responsible for entering the X (sender) and Y(receiver) accounts, the X private keys  and a triggering event before calling the Solidity contract that I named TransactionContract.

I first wanted to deploy my "TransactionContract" contract with the deploy.js script to make sure it works before testing the interactive part that calls this contract (FO_Transact_tk.py).

I think this is not the right solution.

Can you tell me how to proceed for a better way?

Thank you in advance
Claude

Here are the PYTHON script.

```
e#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

## -*- coding:Utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from web3 import Web3
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

## Charger les variables d'environnement depuis un fichier .env

load_dotenv()

## Configuration de Web3 pour se connecter au réseau local (localhost)

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

## Adresse du contrat

contract_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(os.getenv('CONTRACT_ADDRESS'))

## Charger le contrat

with open('TransactionContract.sol', 'r') as file:
contract_source_code = file.readlines()

contract_source_code = ''.join(contract_source_code)
compiled_contract = w3.eth.compile_contract(contract_source_code)

## Adresse de l'utilisateur (compte X)

account_x_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(os.getenv('ACCOUNT_X_ADDRESS'))

## Adresse du compte Y

account_y_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(os.getenv('ACCOUNT_Y_ADDRESS'))

## Clé privée de l'utilisateur (compte X)

private_key = os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY')

## Créer l'instance du contrat

transaction_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=compiled_contract['abi'])

def trigger_transaction():
amount = amount_entry.get()
event_trigger = event_entry.get()

```
# Vérifier si le montant est valide
try:
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Amount must be a positive integer")
except ValueError as e:
    messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))
    return

nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_x_address)
transaction = transaction_contract.functions.triggerTransaction(amount, event_trigger, account_y_address).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': 1,
    'gas': 2000000,
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('50', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce,
})
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"Transaction sent: {tx_hash.hex()}")
```

## Créer la fenêtre Tkinter

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Trigger Transaction")

## Entrée pour le montant

amount_label = tk.Label(root, text="Amount:")
amount_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
amount_entry = tk.Entry(root)
amount_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

## Entrée pour l'événement déclencheur

event_label = tk.Label(root, text="Event Trigger:")
event_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
event_entry = tk.Entry(root)
event_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

## Bouton pour déclencher la transaction

trigger_button = tk.Button(root, text="Trigger Transaction", command=trigger_transaction)
trigger_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")

## Lancer la boucle principale Tkinter

root.mainloop()